# Is it still possible to create new DTS packages on SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dts

I have been trying to create a new Data Transformations Services package from scratch on SQL Server 2008 R2. I do not find the option of creating a new package in the DTS 2000 Package designer, do I have any other alternatives? I couldn't find enough support online for DTS packages.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not create an SSIS package?

Comment: SSIS packages replaced DTS packages

Comment: Have you reviewed the MSDN page on DTS 2000 support in 2008r2? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440(v=sql.105).aspx#designtime